# How to implement append method in our own shell using open system call in c?

Tags: c, linux, shell

I am trying to  implement my own shell in which i have to make a shell feature by which i will able to append text to file by using >>.here is my code....

```
        int filedesc = open(inputargs[limit-1],O_WRONLY | O_APPEND);
                        //printf("%s\n",inputargs[limit-1]);
                        if(filedesc < 0) {
                           printf("Error opening file\n");

                        }
                        else{
                        dup2(filedesc,1);
                        }
```

filedesc always returning -1.

Comment: Are you sure `inputargs[limit-1]` is a correct file path?

Comment: Also I believe O_APPEND automatically gives you write privilege? Could be wrong there..

Comment: Using `O_APPEND` is correct — and you _do_ need `O_WRONLY` too, and maybe `O_CREAT` in case it doesn't exist yet (but you definitely don't want `O_TRUNC`).  I suppose `O_RDWR` would also work (in place of `O_WRONLY`), but it is not a good idea.

Comment: @Irelia yes it is a right path.

Comment: Does the file exist to be appended to?  If not, add `O_CREAT` and a file mode argument.  Tradition says "use 0666" (aka `S_IWUSR | S_IRUSR | S_IWGRP | S_IRGRP | S_IWOTH | S_IROTH` — there's a reason people prefer typing the octal number!).  I'd be sorely tempted to not grant write to group or others, even though you can (and I do) use `umask 022` to suppress those permissions.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler yes file is exist

Comment: What do you get from `perror(inputargs[limit-1]);` (instead of or as well as the `printf()` message?  That will tell you why the system thinks it can't open the file.  And don't forget that the system is right — it can't open the file.  Your code has a problem — it is not yet clear what that is.  It might be EPERM (no permission); it might be ENOENT (no such file or directory); it might be something else, but those two are the most likely.

Comment: getting permission denied from perror(inputargs[limit-1]);

Comment: So, you don't have permission to write on the file — what are you going to do about that?  Change the file name to one you have permission to write on, or set the permissions on the file you have so that you can write (append) to it.  If you somewhere along the line create the file using `O_CREAT` but don't specify the third (optional) argument to `open()`, you get quasi-random weird permissions on the file that you create.  What does `ls -l file-to-append-to` tell you?

Comment: Note that you should always write error messages in a shell to standard error and not to standard output.  Even if there's I/O redirection on standard error, the shell still writes the error messages to standard error, and the redirection points it where the user wanted it to go.

Answer (score 1):

<sup>*Transferring an edited form of my relevant comments into an answer.*</sup>

Using `O_APPEND` is correct — and [you *do* need `O_WRONLY`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75272813/how-to-implement-append-method-in-our-own-shell-using-open-system-call-in-c#comment132825845_75272813) too — and maybe you should add `O_CREAT` in case it doesn't exist yet (but you definitely don't want `O_TRUNC`). I suppose `O_RDWR` would also work (in place of `O_WRONLY`), but it is not a good idea.

Does the file exist to be appended to? If not, add `O_CREAT` and a file mode argument. Tradition says "use 0666" (aka `S_IRUSR | S_IWUSR | S_IRGRP | S_IWGRP | S_IROTH | S_IWOTH` — there's a reason people prefer typing the octal number!). I'd be sorely tempted to not grant write to group or others (using `0644`), even though you can (and I do) use `umask 022` to suppress those permissions.

What do you get from `perror(inputargs[limit-1]);` (instead of or as well as the `printf()` message? That will tell you why the system thinks it can't open the file. And don't forget that the system is right — it can't open the file. Your code has a problem — it is not yet clear what that is. It might be `EPERM` (no permission); it might be `ENOENT` (no such file or directory); it might be something else, but those two are the most likely.

> [Getting "`permission denied`" from `perror(inputargs[limit-1]);`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75272813/how-to-implement-append-method-in-our-own-shell-using-open-system-call-in-c/75273033#comment132825919_75272813)

So, you don't have permission to write on the file — what are you going to do about that? Change the file name to one you have permission to write on, or set the permissions on the file you have so that you can write (append) to it?  Or something else?  If you, somewhere along the line, create the file using `O_CREAT` but don't specify the third (optional) argument to `open()`, you get quasi-random weird permissions on the file that you create. What does `ls -l file-to-append-to` tell you?  (Note that the third argument is mandatory when `O_CREAT` is one of the options used in the call to `open()` — it is optional and ignored otherwise.)

Note that you should always write error messages in a shell to standard error and not to standard output. Even if there's I/O redirection on standard error, the shell still writes the error messages to standard error, and the redirection points it where the user wanted it to go.